# Check value of both text boxes if they have values in it or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page have multiple textboxes i wanted to make sure if user select value from text box 1 and leaves text box 2 empty then it should alert a popup that you must have to enter values in both textboxes.

i do not want to compare values with each other.(Like both textbox value must be same)

Textbox 1 is Number field and text box 2 is date field.

If any one value is entered then it should not allow user to submit page it should stop processing and redirect to that textbox which is empty.

Now what i have tried so far.

```
$( "#button_id" ).click(function() {

var n = document.getElementById('text1');
var m = document.getElementById('text2');


if(n.value.trim() != "" || n.value == undefined)
{
    if (n.value.trim() != "" && m.value.trim() == "")
    {
        alert("text1 should have some value");
        return false;
    }
} 
if(m.value.trim() != "" || m.value == undefined)
{
    if (m.value.trim() != "" && n.value.trim() == "")
    {
        alert("text2 should have some values");
        return false;
    }
} 

});
```

As mention below code i just wanted to check if textbox is disable or not if textbox is disable then do not test for validation else do.

Partial Solution :

```
 var _domArray = [$("#textbox1"),$("#textbox2")]
 var chk = $x('textbox2').disabled = false;

 $( "buttonid" ).click(function() {

 _domArray.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.val() ==''){
  var _getId =item.attr('id');
  alert(_getId +" should have some value" );
  this.browserEvent.preventDefault();  
  this.browserEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();  
  return false;   
 }
 })
 });
```

Comment: You have said what you want and what you tried, missing what is the problem with your current code

Comment: the following checks should be the other way round - check undefined first. m.value.trim() != "" || m.value == undefined

Comment: @juvian Above code will check for values and popup alert window as i mention above but page gets submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `required` attribute on your `<input>`s, then you can check in JavaScript with `document.querySelector('form.insertSelectorHere').matches(':valid')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store the DOM element,Loop through it and check to check if it is empty, If so through an alert.

Also assuming you are using input type number & date

```
var _domArray = [$("#text1"),$("#text2")]
$( "#button_id" ).click(function() {
 _domArray.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.val() ==''){
      var _getId =item.attr('id');
      alert(_getId +" should have some value" )
   }
})
});
```

Using jquery since you have tagged this with jquery

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yy145pq/1/)

Comment: Thank you for you're kind response can we stop processing page if any value is not entered right now page gets submitted.

Comment: How are you submitting using ajax?

Comment: Actually its different tool called EBS oracle...so i we do not need ajax for that.

Comment: need to see how you are submitting the form

Comment: i have multiple text box on page can we do something like if only textbox1 have value in it then it should show validation if both are empty then no validation at all